# How is the event parameter passed when using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I’m confused by the following code on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_transition_propertyName.asp):

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("transitionend", myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
  this.innerHTML = "Property name is: " + event.propertyName;
}
```

How is it that `myFunction()` can have a parameter `event` reference passed in when the preceding statement call merely passed in `myFunction` *without any arguments*?

Doesn’t that constitute an undeclared variable usage in normal circumstances?

Are there any other such occurences elsewhere in the DOM event I should be aware of?

Comment: By the way, this behavior is not exclusive to the DOM API. This really is a property of JavaScript, not the DOM, not events, not HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myFunction` is just the function reference. It does not call the function on its own. When passed to `addEventListener`, `myFunction` is called “at some point in time”. Exactly how it’s called is decided by `addEventListener` itself, so the call can still be something like

```
myFunction(someEventObject);
```

The argument is passed by the API.

Other examples include:

- `new MutationObserver(function(mutations){`…`})`, where `mutations` is passed to the function when a DOM mutation occurs, containing an array of mutations.
- `new Promise(function(resolve, reject){`…`})` where `resolve` and `reject` are provided as two functions to be called whenever an asynchronous action is “resolved” or “rejected”.
- `[1, 2, 4].map(function(item, index, array){`…`})` where `item` is `1`, `2` or `4` at `index` `0`, `1` or `2` respectively, and `array` being the array being iterated.

And many more.

---

You can make a function like this yourself.

Consider this example where a function `action` is executed after two seconds, because it’s passed into another function called `executeTwoSecondsLater`.

Suppose, we need the `time`, when `action` is finally executed within the function itself.

```js
// Provided by the API:

function executeTwoSecondsLater(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(new Date().toString());
  }, 2000);
}

// Written by the user:

function action(time) {
  console.log(`The time of execution is ${time}.`);
}

executeTwoSecondsLater(action);
```

`time` is provided by `executeTwoSecondsLater`.

Comment: Thanks for the qn refinement and explanations @Xufox!  Can you tell me where I can find out what arguments do the Web APIS pass? Using your example of .map() function [link])https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).  Where on the page does it say what arguments were passed? (trying to learn how to read such docs)

Comment: @Theo That’s not the right documentation, this is: [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This is about the `map` method on `Array`s; the other one about the `Map` object. In the _Syntax_ section it says `var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {`…`}[, thisArg])`, with `currentValue`, `index`, and `array` being explained down below.

Comment: Thanks for the link and great explanation :)